# Android Studio cannot open a project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osx-yosemite

I have a big bug on Android Studio (OS X 10.10). When i opened my android project, i saw the interface with no side explorer and just grey screen... and nothing happened.

This problem appeared only since this morning.

[image: Android Studio]

Comment: That's quite little information to work on...

Comment: Try to Go **View-->Tool Windows-->Project** or Press **Alt + 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should uninstall fabric plugin and restart android studio.

I had same problem too
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178464