# Can not open a project on android studio (All project files can not open)

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

I am working on Android studio 4.1.1. Everything was working correctly and smoothly. Suddenly I do not know what happened so that the Android studio can not open any of my projects, not access the Java file (e.g. Main activity, and other classes). It is like freezing and can not open any code file. The below pic show the problem.

[image: screenshot of android studio]

I tried to invalidate the cache and restart Android studio several times, but not working. I searched and found threads talking about "Uninstalling fabric plugin from the android studio". However, I can not uninstall the fabric plugin because the "File/ settings" tab of android studio is not working and I do not know how exactly I can uninstall it.

[Android Studio cannot open a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135768/android-studio-cannot-open-a-project)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37052242

Can anyone help me to fix this, please?

Comment: Please refer this link. This will answer your question too [Android Studio can't open any projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31128533/android-studio-cant-open-any-projects) Please tell me if this works.

Comment: The link you mentioned refers to the same answer (which is uninstall the fabric plugins) that the link I have posted in my question has. I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling the Android Studio platform and then disabled some unnecessary plugins. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by uninstalling and reinstalling the Android Studio platform (updated it from version 4.1.1 to Artic Fox| 2020.3.1 Patch 3) and then disabled some unnecessary plugins. Now it works fine.